# How to map multi-stage docker to multiple Jenkins stages

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am wondering if it's possible to map a multi-stage Dockerfile build to multiple stages in jenkins, instead of one (potentially) massive 'build docker' stage in Jenkins?

e.g. if I run my linters in the Dockerfile, can I map that to one stage in Jenkins? 
Then run tests...etc.

I am using groovy in a Jenkinsfile.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Those commands should result from running containers and not building images, and those can be mapped to different stages in Jenkins.

Comment: Do you think you could expand on what you mean as the difference? And how I would organize that in my repository? I'm happy to change the way things are done if it results in a decoupled build process. We are using yarn to build/test/productionize in a single Dockerfile and using alpine-node as the base for each stage.